# How can I implement Logto with my own UI?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

In my primary Next.js project, I already have a UI design. I'm interested in only the user management feature. Is it possible to directly request sign-in/sign-up through the Logto API?

Comment: I believe the sign in page is on their servers so it is limited but you have some possibilities to customize. See https://docs.logto.io/docs/recipes/customize-sie/